Searching for an episode where a character’s childhood flashes as his parent kills him
I realize this is a long shot; the flashback trope is so common that, although I’ve tried to search for it, results are flooded with other media, so hoping someone here remembers it.
It’s an episode of TV where a character (male, adult) is killed. I believe the character was a bad guy and the killing is portrayed as necessary. However, the character’s parent (mother?) is there (possibly the one doing the killing), and as the character dies, she experiences a rapid flashback of his life from early childhood, including an image of him as a young boy with blond hair on a sunny day, as a way of dramatizing her grief at losing him, and at what he became.
I think this was a fantasy TV show, akin to Buffy in tone/theme, but I could be entirely misremembering that.
Any leads are appreciated!

In roughly which year did you watch this? And how was the character killed?

Probably sometime 2010-2015. I believe the character is stabbed in the chest, or a similar method that involves being close up and face to face.

I do not remember clearly,  but world according to garp had a scene like that
